# Accessing CodeIgniter super object from external php script outside codeigniter installation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying so long but couldn't find a solution. For some reason I need to access the codeigniter super object get_instance() from an external php script which is located outside codeigniter installation.

So for example, I have a custom php script called my_script.php inside public_html. And the codeigniter is installed inside public_html/codeigniter.

Followed by the discussion here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/101620/ I created a file called external.php and put it inside public_html/codeigniter folder, it contains the following code:

```
<?php
// Remove the query string
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '';
// Include the codeigniter framework
ob_start();
require('./new/index.php');
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Then I created a file called my_script.php and put it inside public_html folder (outside codeigniter installation), it contains the following code:

```
<?php
require('new/external.php');
$ci =& get_instance();
echo $ci->somemodel->somemethod();
?>
```

Now when I load the my_script.php file from browser, it produces following error:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

If I put the my_script.php file inside codeigniter folder with corrected file path in require() function then it works. But I really need it to work from outside codeigniter installation.

Any idea how to get rid of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CI's main `index.php` sets the paths of the system and application folders. If you are including `index.php` from another directory, these paths are set relative to your "including" directory.

Try changing the following lines in `index.php`

```
$system_path = 'system';
// change to...
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'system';

// and...
$application_folder = 'application';
// change to...
$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application';
```

The `dirname(__FILE__)` will give you the absolute path of the `index.php` even if you include it somewhere else.

Comment: You have solved my problem. Thank you. However, I am now running into another problem. That, when I call index.php file from an external file, the class/method defined in default_controller is called. How can I avoid his? Because in default_controller function, I have some conditions and redirections, which I do not want to apply when calling from an external script. Any idea?

Comment: I've never included CI in another project using that method. But on top of my head, a quick hack is to set a constant in your custom php script to tell CI, you are "including" it. In your default controller's constructor and method, check if the constant is defined and `return` right away before any code runs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with loading codeigniter from external file outside codeigniter installation is solved using the first answer which I marked as accepted. And the problem with calling default controller/method was resolved using constant (define). Here is the updated code for external.php file:

```
<?php
// Remove the query string
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '';
// Include the codeigniter framework
define("REQUEST", "external");
ob_start();
require('./new/index.php');
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

And here is the default controller method:

```
public function index($flag = NULL) 
 {
  if (constant("REQUEST") != "external")
  {
    // some code here
  }
 }
```

Thanks very much to contributor hyubs. @hyubs