# Access CodeIgniter Object in external php file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on an application (using Codeigniter framework) which needs an external php script to run separately. I want to access the Codeigniter object like this in that external file:

```
$CI =&get_instance();
```

the external file is placed in `application/helpers/script.php`

I followed [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879659/accessing-codeigniter-super-object-from-external-php-script-outside-codeigniter)  but it didn't work for me.

also I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926455/access-codeigniter-session-values-from-external-files):-

```
ob_start();
include('index.php');
ob_end_clean();
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session'); //if it's not autoloaded in your CI setup
echo $CI->session->userdata('name');
```

but it generates errors like "Constant" already defined.

How can I access the Codeigniter object in the external file?

Comment: If it's codeigniter that needs your external script and not the opposite, have you considered writing a CI library ?

Comment: Actually, its the "External script" that need to use Codeigniter.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also have a script (placed in the root folder, alongside CI's index.php) and I need it to access CI methods.

Comment: no sorry :( , What i did i make a separate folder in Codeignitor and create a separate logic for it.