# Codeigniter 3 - Access Session from Outside Codeigniter Installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I can't seem to get session data passed from my codeigniter application back to a script in my includes folder. From what I've read on other answers, I need to set my `session_id()` to be able to rejoin a session with `session_start()`.

```
ROOT /
     .. /application
     .. /system
     .. /includes
        .. /Events.php <- I need access from here
```

Theoretically the code below should work, at least according to other answers, because the new CI session library passes on to native sessions.

```
session_id($_COOKIE['ci_session']);
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); // returns null
```

Am I misunderstanding sessions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access codeigniter session values from external files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926455/access-codeigniter-session-values-from-external-files)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original answer from @wolfgang1983 [Ben Swinburne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7926691/3629438) combined with an answer here: from [Atiqur Rahman Sumon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23892987/3629438)

You can include the `index.php` from any directory, however, you need to change the `$system_path` and `$application_folder` variables to match your relative location. Well that's great if you want to completely change your whole application's paths, but I didn't want to, so I just copied the `index.php` file into the directory I needed to include codeigniter with.

```
ROOT /
     .. /application
     .. /system
     .. /includes
        .. /Events.php <- I need access from here
        .. /index.php <- Copied CI index with new paths
     .. /index.php
```

In `/includes/index.php`:

```
//$system_path = 'system';
$system_path = '../system';

//$application_folder = 'application';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

Now you can include codeigniter in your file with the:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('index.php');
    ob_end_clean();
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('session'); //if it's not autoloaded in your CI setup
    echo $CI->session->userdata('name');
?>
```

If you refresh your page now, you would **end up with the default controller loaded.**

So taking from Atiqur Rahman Sumon's answer, we can define a constant before load to tell the default controller we want to skip it's normal callstack.

```
ob_start();
define("REQUEST", "external"); <--
include('index.php');
ob_end_clean();
```

And in your `default_controller.php`:

```
function index()
{
    if (REQUEST == "external") {
        return;
    } 

    //other code for normal requests.
}
```

Comment: Hats off for this answer. Genuinely saved a great deal of confusion as to why an AJAX request was loading the login screen's HTML of our app!

Comment: @PaulSkinner glad I could help!

Comment: this is the best solution for those who want to use CI as their backend framework :). Like me i need to use wordpress as my front end and i need a hard code one to add a new login dashboard and this will take place.

Comment: Best answer. Still valid for CodeIgniter Version 3.1.9

Answer (score 3):

Improving on @acupajoe's answer, you don't have to copy-paste the CI `index.php`. Instead change the `include` part into this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    define("REQUEST", "external");
    $temp_system_path = 'path/to/system/folder/from/external/file';
    $temp_application_folder = 'path/to/application/folder/from/external/file';
    include('path/to/index.php/file/from/external/file');
    ob_end_clean();
    $CI =& get_instance();
    //...
?>
```

Then change in `index.php`:

```
$system_path = isset($temp_system_path) ? $temp_system_path : 'system';
```

and

```
$application_folder = isset($temp_application_folder) ? $temp_application_folder : 'application';
```

Comment: Thumbs up for `define("REQUEST", "external");`. Add this line and your site won't redirect to other pages if your `index.php` always redirecting to other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [access codeigniter session values from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926455/access-codeigniter-session-values-from-external-files) it may help what you after.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('index.php');
    ob_end_clean();
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('session'); //if it's not autoloaded in your CI setup
    echo $CI->session->userdata('name');
?>
```