# How to include Codeigniter from external page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to be able to check a page outside of the CodeIgniter environment to see if a user is logged in.

My setup might be as follows:

```
test.php

/codeigniter/index.php
```

In my CodeIgniter application, I have a method which checks to see if a user loggedin:

```
if($this->user->loggedin) {
    // Logged in
} else {
   // not logged in
}
```

It's basically calling my user class and checking the loggedin variable. It's easy to use inside the CodeIgniter environment.

How can I use the CodeIgniter functions from my script test.php?

Answer (score -1):

You could set a cookie in CI that your test.php page can check. That would do it.

Or here is something that might help:
[Accessing CodeIgniter super object from external php script outside codeigniter installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879659/accessing-codeigniter-super-object-from-external-php-script-outside-codeigniter)

Comment: You asked two questions, I gave two seperate suggestions? Why the down vote?